# What is the first event which I can use ShowMessage on Delphi XE + FireMonkey forms

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe6

I am developing a mobile application which requires an online internet connection.
I have called `CheckInternetConnection` codes in `Form.OnCreate` this method checks the intenet connection and will show a `MessageBox` which is saying you are not connected.
When I run this app on `ios Simulator` or `ios Device`, there is just `SplashScreen` and the app will stay there forever. I thought `MessageBox` goes under the splash screen, so I decided to move my code to other events, I tried `OnPaint`, `OnActivate`, `OnResize` but all of them are same.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Won't a quick test app and the debugger give you that information?

Comment: @KenWhite Just create a firemonkey mobile application, double click on the form and write a ShowMessage('Hello') in the OnCreate. run it on Simulator or Device, Splash screen will appear and this is the end. Your form or message won't show ever.

Comment: You can use `Application.OnIdle` (when called first time) or a `TTimer` (Interval 1ms when called first time). There is no message/event for Application.IsReady

Comment: @SirRufo It works (Application.OnIdle), you are great man.

Answer (score -1):

Try using Form.OnShow this will call the MessageBox when the form is first shown. Make sure to use a boolean flag in order to not show the message twice

Comment: No bro, it is not working, just create an application and write ShowMessage in the FormShow and see the result.

Comment: I tried it again and it works like a charm... Added the following code to the form:                                                     procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.MessageBox('hi','hi',1);
end;                                                                 Doesn't it work for you?

Comment: @Dori: On iOS it works different. Calling Showmessage in FormShow will lock the application like RezaRahmati said.